# How to extract a section from web.config in a seperate file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have the following section in `Web.config` :

```
 <httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <remove name="X-UA-Compatible" />
    <remove name="X-Frame-Options" />
    <remove name="X-XSS-Protection" />
    <remove name="X-Content-Type-Options" />
    <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=Edge" />
    <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="DENY" />
    <add name="X-XSS-Protection" value="1; mode=block"></add>
    <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

and I would like to extract `<customHeaders>` to a config file with the name `web.customer.customHeaders.config`. In order to achieve this, I have created the `web.customer.customHeaders.config` file in tha same location where my `Web.config` is and I have written the folowing XML in it:

```
<customHeaders>
    <remove name="X-UA-Compatible" />
    <remove name="X-Frame-Options" />
    <remove name="X-XSS-Protection" />
    <remove name="X-Content-Type-Options" />
    <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=Edge" />
    <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="DENY" />
    <add name="X-XSS-Protection" value="1; mode=block"></add>
    <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff" />
  </customHeaders>
```

I have also chsnged the `<customHeaders>` section in my `Web.config` file as such:

```
 <httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders configSource="web.customer.customHeaders.config" />
</httpProtocol>
```

but unfortunately, the `configSource` attribute is not recognised. As a result, the extracted file, cannot be read and be inserted into my `Web.config` file.

My question is: How can I extract a section from web.config in a seperate file.

In case you have any clue how this managable is, please leave a comment below.

Comment: `the configSource attribute is not recognised.` Is the IDE indicating that somehow? Or you are experiencing it at runtime?

Comment: @mjwills : Yes. There is a squiggly line and when I go with my mouse over, I become the hint "The 'configSource' is not allowed."

Comment: And when you run it does it work? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5980776/34092

Comment: This might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232059/reading-settings-from-separate-config-file

Comment: When you say extract I thought it means extracting through code. This works for console app.config. Should not be different with  web.config `Configuration configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
            var section = configuration.GetSection("runtime");
            File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Temp\section.config", section.SectionInformation.GetRawXml());`

Comment: @mjwills: The code compiles, but I get an error "500.19 - Internal Server Error: The requested page can not be accessed because its configuration information for the page is invalid." whe I try to load the Application.

Comment: @mjwills: I am afraid I am not allowed to upload the whole configuration. I can assure you that the application runs properly if I take my changes back.

Comment: Does the configSource file have an xml Element header indicated as required in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/398632/2592875)?

Comment: @mjwills: It will not make any difference if I just added the XML header to my seperate file, because the problem is that the "configSource" attribute is not recognised as an attribute for the "customHeader" tag.

Comment: @Nilesh: I got a little bit confused. I think I need only some XML code.

Answer (score 3):

Not all sections allow a `configSource` attribute; customHeaders is such one.
The XSD schema Visual Studio uses to validate the content of eg. `web.config` confirms this.
You find this file in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Xml\Schemas\1033\DotNetConfig.xsd` (unless you installed elsewhere).

A fragment of the `customHeaders` declaration shows there is no `configSource` attribute.

```
<xs:element name="customHeaders">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element name="add">
        <!-- ... -->
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="remove">
        <!-- ... -->
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="clear">
        <!-- ... -->
      </xs:element>
    </xs:choice>
    <xs:anyAttribute />
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

In `DotNetConfig.xsd` you find which elements/sections do support this attribute; eg. `connectionStrings` and `appSettings`.

Comment: Looked at the XSD file and now I'm learning the location section/element is another section that does not allow configSource attribute; damn!. I wanted to place location elements in a separate file but will have to live with a larger web.config. Thanks pfx!